# Is this study linking RFR and Cancer valid?

Tags: cancer

Came across this study on sciencedaily.com that was a review of the results from a hundred other RFR studies and they determined that there is a definitive link between radio frequency radiation and cancer through the oxidative stress RFR places on cells:

http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.3109/15368378.2015.1043557

And this study has received next to no media coverage. With RFR impacting so many people it makes me wonder, is this study valid? I would expect this to be front page news.

Answer (score 5):

As stated [there](http://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancercauses/radiationexposureandcancer/radiofrequency-radiation),

> Most animal and laboratory studies have found no evidence of an increased risk of cancer with exposure to RF radiation. A few studies have reported evidence of biological effects that could be linked to cancer.

But

> Studies of people who may have been exposed to RF radiation at their jobs (such as people who work around or with radar equipment, those who service communication antennae, and radio operators) have found no clear increase in cancer risk.

It also says it's not been possible yet to estabilish whether a link between cell phones and cancer exists at all.

The worst effect it sure has is tissue heating due to the sub-ionizing frequencies' water-heating property.

It also stated [there](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1469962/), at [page 1567](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1469962/?page=3), that

> There is no evidence for such a link (RF exposure and increased cancer incidency)

Furthermore, [here is an article](http://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/radiation/cell-phones-fact-sheet) which will clarify most of your doubts, it says:

> Although there have been some concerns that radiofrequency energy from cell phones held closely to the head may affect the brain and other tissues, to date there is no evidence from studies of cells, animals, or humans that radiofrequency energy can cause cancer.

My personal conclusion are that it's mostly harmless to be around EMFs in the RF spectrum, though you should not abuse them, nor expose to any dangerous (ionizing) EMF without proper protection.

Remember Paracelsus,

> Sola dosis facit venenum

or

> The dose makes the poison

Live long and prosper. Have a nice day

EDIT: I had the time to check the study quoted, it says they found a link between RFR and Oxidative pathways' triggering, it only **deduced** it could cause

> Both cancer and non-cancer pathologies

I think there is not a relation, at least in complex organisms, because we're talking about specialized tissues which can help shielding the inner organs (e.g. the skin protects us from most radiations, both high and low intensity ones)

As before, Have a nice day